# Преобразование изображения в byte, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, база-данных

в этом окне я произвожу SQL - запрос INSERT в бд таблицы Cars, но на строке 65 Image Converter выдаёт ошибку (ImageSourceConverter' не может преобразовать 'System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage' в 'System.Byte[]'."
)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;
using f = System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SQLite;

namespace DrivingApp
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Логика взаимодействия для Car.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Car : Window
    {

        private SQLiteConnection db = null;
        private SQLiteCommand cmd = null;
        public Car()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            db = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Driving"].ConnectionString);
            db.Open();
        }

        private void Button_Img_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog ofd = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            ofd.Filter = "Image Files(* .BMP; *.JPG;*GIF;*.PNG)| *.BMP;*.JPG; *.GIF, *.PNG | All files (*.*)|*.*";
            Nullable<bool> result = ofd.ShowDialog();
            if (result == true)
            {
                try
                {
                     pictureBox.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(ofd.FileName));
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Невозмодно открыть выбранный файл");
                }
            }
        }
        private void Button_Car_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
     
            string coach = textBoxCoach.Text;
            string mark = textBoxMark.Text;
            string color = textBoxColor.Text;
            string year = textBoxYear.Text;

            ImageSource pimg = pictureBox.Source;
            ImageSourceConverter Converter = new ImageSourceConverter();
            var ImageSourceConverter = Converter.ConvertTo(pimg, typeof(byte[]));

            if (coach.Length > 20)
            {
                textBoxCoach.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                textBoxCoach.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            } else if (mark.Length > 10)
            {
                textBoxMark.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                textBoxMark.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            }
            else if (color.Length > 10)
            {
                 textBoxColor.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                 textBoxColor.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            }
            else if (year.Length > 25)
            {
                 textBoxYear.ToolTip = "Это поле введено некорректно";
                 textBoxYear.Background = Brushes.DarkRed;
            }
            else
            {
                 textBoxCoach.ToolTip = "";
                 textBoxCoach.Background = Brushes.Green;
                 textBoxMark.ToolTip = "";
                 textBoxMark.Background = Brushes.Green;
                 textBoxColor.ToolTip = "";
                 textBoxColor.Background = Brushes.Green;
                 textBoxYear.ToolTip = "";
                 textBoxYear.Background = Brushes.Green;

                 cmd = db.CreateCommand();
                 cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Cars (Mark, Color, Year, Coach, Image) VALUES (@mar, @col, @yea, @coa, @img)";
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mar", mark);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@col", color);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yea", year);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@coa", coach);
                 cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@img", ImageSourceConverter);
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                 MessageBox.Show("Accound created");

                 
            }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Вот весь код логики моего окна, у меня выходит только эта ошибка. Пожалуйста помогите, заранее большое вам спасибо!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6597746/12888024

Comment: Можете пожалуйста написать подробнее как на моём примере, ну или как можно исправить мою ошибку?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/29384523/312041 ?

Comment: Можете пожалуйста коротко написать как будет в моём примере, всё что я хочу чтобы картинку которую я выбираю в ImageSoure сохранялась в БД SQlite в байтовом формате